# Why Tesseract cannot recognize my image?

Tags: ocr

Please see image: http://s18.postimg.org/wvwj4yt4l/ashx.jpg

I think my image is very simple but tesseract-ocr cannot recognize  correct it :( It show "AÂ§Â§Â§SX", not A9FCCC

Please tell me why? How to tesseract can recognize it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The basic Tesseract Engine is **not meant for CPATCHA breaking**. It will mostly do fine with scanned pages from print media, even if the text/letter angle is not perfectly horizontal.
Distortion and pixellation - in a mild degree - also won't be much of a problem.

But **letters with** (drastically) **malformed shapes** like the one you linked, **will not be recognized**. OCR and especially CAPTCHA breaking is much more complex than downloading the Tesseract binaries. If it were that easy, all of the paid services would be out of business over night. The OCR topic is so complex that I personally don't dare to touch it.

Comment: I think it's simple captcha because many people at my country can read it. But I cannot :( Please help me iff you can